# Store JWT in a NextJS app with a Spring backend

Tags: spring, cookies, next.js, jwt

I'm currently building an app using NextJS and some Spring microservices backend, but have encountered some doubts regarding the handling of the JWT.

My problem is that I want to create private pages, so I was storing my JWT token that comes from my Spring backend in an Authorization header and I was storing it on local storage, but when I try to grab my token on `ServerSideProps` I can't access local storage, so I went to find another solution to where to store my token.

I found out that you can store the token in an HTTP-ONLY cookie, but I have some doubts:

1. If I save my token on an HTTP-ONLY Cookie in my Spring Security
   microservice when the user logs in, it will be available to grab at
   any time on my `ServerSideProps` on NextJS frontend? Or I will have
   to somehow save it in my frontend when receiving the response from
   `/login`?
2. I have an AuthContext which stores the logged user, should I instead ditch cookies and localstorage and just store the JWT here in context and then somehow grabbed it on ServerSideProps, even though you can't access a hook inside there.

I need a little guidance on how people solved this issue using a custom backend, have looked through Google but people mostly use third party auth providers.

Answer (score 0):

Storing cookies in the browser is today a bad idea due to the various security problems that comes with doing that.

A better idea today is to use the BFF pattern as described here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf